# MyBatis Spring boot MultiDataSource SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: Connection closed, Authentication lapse 0 ms.)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource, mybatis

I'm trying to configure my spring-boot application to use 2 datasource at the same time.

When I call the service that use one of the two (taDatasource) I get "IO Error: Connection closed", does this mean the connection properties are wrong or am I doing something else wrong?

Could you please help me?

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: Connection closed, Authentication lapse 0 ms.)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:307)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at com.gy7.rental.service.RentalServiceImpl.findAllTestDataItems(RentalServiceImpl.java:37)
    at com.gy7.rental.controller.RentalController.searchMessage(RentalController.java:268)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:666)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: Connection closed, Authentication lapse 0 ms.)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:669)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:544)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:753)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:263)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection closed, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:821)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:782)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:704)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:55)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:355)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:115)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:665)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection closed, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:817)
    ... 98 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection closed
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.readFromSocket(SSLSocketChannel.java:560)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.unwrapHandshakeMessage(SSLSocketChannel.java:479)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.doSSLHandshake(SSLSocketChannel.java:436)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.write(SSLSocketChannel.java:126)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.writeToSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:308)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOConnectPacket.writeToSocketChannel(NIOConnectPacket.java:235)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:114)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:318)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1481)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:540)
    ... 98 more
25-10-2022 19:00:19.980 [ERROR] - [https-jsse-nio-27100-exec-3] c.u.g.m.c.RentalController : Exception message: 
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: Connection closed, Authentication lapse 0 ms.)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:307)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at com.gy7.rental.service.RentalServiceImpl.findAllTestDataItems(RentalServiceImpl.java:37)
    at com.gy7.rental.controller.RentalController.searchMessage(RentalController.java:268)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:666)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: Connection closed, Authentication lapse 0 ms.)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:669)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:544)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:753)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:263)
    ... 88 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection closed, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:821)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:782)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:704)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:55)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:355)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:115)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:665)
    ... 91 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection closed, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:817)
    ... 98 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection closed
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.readFromSocket(SSLSocketChannel.java:560)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.unwrapHandshakeMessage(SSLSocketChannel.java:479)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.doSSLHandshake(SSLSocketChannel.java:436)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.write(SSLSocketChannel.java:126)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.writeToSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:308)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOConnectPacket.writeToSocketChannel(NIOConnectPacket.java:235)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:114)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:318)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1481)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:540)
    ... 98 common frames omitted
```

TaDataSourceConfiguration.java:

```
    @Configuration
@MapperScan(value = {"com.gy7.rental.jdbc.mapper"}, sqlSessionFactoryRef = "taSqlSessionFactory")
public class TaDataSourceConfiguration extends DataSourceConfiguration {


    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TaDataSourceConfiguration.class);

    @Bean("taDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "jdbc-oracle-tadb")
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "jdbc-oracle-tadb.enable", havingValue = "true")
    @Primary
    public DataSource taDataSource() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Creating Oracle TA datasource.");
        BasicDataSource bds = createTADataSource();
        LOGGER.info("Oracle TA datasource created. Datasource: {}", bds);
        return bds;
    }

    @Bean(name = "taSqlSessionFactory")
    @Primary
    public SqlSessionFactory taSqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(createTADataSource());
        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "taTrxManager")
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    protected BasicDataSource createTADataSource() throws Exception {

        BasicDataSource bds = new BasicDataSource();
        bds.setUrl(System.getProperty("DB_TA_URL"));
        bds.setUsername("MIKE");
        bds.setPassword("123456");
        bds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        bds.setInitialSize(5);
        bds.setMaxTotal(GenericObjectPoolConfig.DEFAULT_MAX_TOTAL);
        bds.setMaxIdle(GenericObjectPoolConfig.DEFAULT_MAX_IDLE);
        bds.setMinIdle(GenericObjectPoolConfig.DEFAULT_MIN_IDLE);
        bds.setMaxWaitMillis(5000L);
        bds.setDefaultQueryTimeout(10);  // seconds
        bds.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(30);  // seconds

        return bds;
    }
```

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
        "com.gy7.rental"
},
        exclude = {
                ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
                DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class
        }
)
@MapperScan("com.gy7.rental.jdbc.mapper")

public class Application
        extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application =
                new SpringApplication(Application.class);

        application.setAddCommandLineProperties(false);
        application.run(args);
    }
}
```

RentalServiceImpl.java

```
    @Service
public class RentalServiceImpl implements RentalServiceIntf {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RentalServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("taSqlSessionFactory")
    SqlSessionFactory taSqlSession;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("taTrxManager")
    private PlatformTransactionManager taTrxManager;

    public List<TestItemEntity> findAllTestDataItems() throws Exception {

        // TA Datasource
        List<TestItemEntity> TestItemEntityList;
        TransactionStatus txStatus = taTrxManager.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition());
        SqlSession session = taSqlSession.openSession();

        try {
            RentalMapper rentalMapper = session.getMapper(RentalMapper.class);
            TestItemEntityList = rentalMapper.selectAllTestDataItem();

            taTrxManager.commit(txStatus);

            if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.debug("# n° records found: {}", TestItemEntityList.size());
            }
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            taTrxManager.rollback(txStatus);
            throw throwable;
        }
        return TestItemEntityList;
    }


}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>${ojdbc.artifactId}</artifactId>
        <version>${ojdbc.version}</version>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.dynamic-sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-dynamic-sql</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you trying to use TLS encryption? There seems to be an [issue](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2771092_1.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the createTADataSource function, check to see if System.getProperty("DB_TA_URL") can successfully get the value, and change the code you used to set setPassword twice